# Manipulation of an array sent by ajax to a php file, within a function of another file

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, ajax

I have an array defined in JS and I am sending it by AJAX to a PHP file called aux.php. What I need, is that this array can be visible and manipulated in a function inside a class of another php file called payments.php.

I passed them all the code so they can understand what I'm doing:

**HTML with form:**

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" id="formCash">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="registroUsuario" name="registroUsuario" placeholder="Nombre Completo" maxlength="26" required>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="registroDireccion" name="registroDireccion" placeholder="Dirección de envío con altura de calle" required>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="registroCalendario" name="registroCalendario" placeholder="Día de envío" required>

    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="registroEmail" name="registroEmail" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" maxlength="32" required>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="registroTelefono" name="registroTelefono" placeholder="Teléfono de contacto" maxlength="16" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" required>       

      <?php

      $payments = new Payments();
      $payments -> ctrCash();

      ?>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-default backColor btnPagar" id="btnPagar" value="CONFIRMAR PEDIDO">

</form>
```

**Function in Javascript that contains the array and sends it by AJAX to aux.php:**

```
$("#btnPagar").click(function(){ 

    var total = $(".valorTotalCompra").html();

    var envio = $(".valorTotalEnvio").html();

    var subtotal = $(".valorSubtotal").html();

    var titulo = $(".valorTitulo");

    var cantidad = $(".valorCantidad");

    var valorItem = $(".valorItem");

    var idProducto = $('.cuerpoCarrito button, .comprarAhora button');

    var tituloArray = [];
    var cantidadArray = [];
    var valorItemArray = [];
    var idProductoArray = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < (titulo.length/2); i++){

        tituloArray[i] = $(titulo[i]).html();
        cantidadArray[i] = $(cantidad[i]).html();
        valorItemArray[i] = $(valorItem[i]).html();
        idProductoArray[i] = $(idProducto[i]).attr("idProducto");

    }

    var finalArray = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < (tituloArray.length); i++){

        finalArray[i] = {titulo : tituloArray[i], cantidad : cantidadArray[i], valorItem : valorItemArray[i], idProducto : idProductoArray[i]}

    }

    completeArray = JSON.stringify(finalArray);

    $.ajax({                        
       type: "POST",                 
       url: "aux.php",                  
       data: { completeArray : completeArray }, 
       success: function(data) {

        console.log(data);

       }

    });

})
```

**File aux.php where the array arrives correctly and var_dump gives me the correct result:**

```
if(isset($_POST['completeArray'])){

$completeArray = json_decode($_POST['completeArray'], true);

var_dump("The array is", $completeArray);
```

Class and function of the payments.php file that validates the fields of the server-side form **and this is where I need to be able to manipulate the array**:

```
class Payments {

    public function ctrCash(){

        if(isset($_POST["registroUsuario"])){

            if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', $_POST["registroUsuario"]) &&
               preg_match('/^([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(\/|-)(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\2(\d{4})$/', $_POST["registroCalendario"]) &&
               preg_match('/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/', $_POST["registroEmail"]) &&
               preg_match('/^(?:\D*\d){2,4}\D*$/', $_POST["registroDireccion"]) &&
               preg_match('/^[0-9]{7,12}$/', $_POST["registroTelefono"])) {

                //include ('aux.php');

}
```

Comment: one thing that stands out to me is that you are passing your variable called "completeArray" but referring to "arrayCompleto" in your json_decode in php.

Comment: @imvain2 I'm sorry, I copied wrong. Now I modify it.

Comment: Just pass `$completeArray` to the ctrCash method by reference. That is, change your function definition to `public function ctrCash(&$completeArray)` and then when you call it, pass the main $completeArray as a parameter. (The `&` makes it pass by reference, so it can be directly modified, instead of pass by value, the default option which copies it to a new object.)

Comment: @IceMetalPunk Taking into account my code, when and where should I do it? Because if you see, I call ctrCash inside the HTML form.

Comment: That's.... not how data transmission works. That PHP code in your HTML form will run once before the form renders. It won't have access to anything submitted after that. You're submitting that data to a totally different PHP script (aux.php). It's never going to somehow get back to the main PHP script.

What you should be doing is having the aux.php script call the ctrCash() function and then echo the result (best practice: convert it to JSON before outputting). Then the Javascript can write the result to page when the AJAX request completes.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk Could you write an answer with an example of the way you intend the array to work within the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, your PHP output only gets generated when the script first runs, before the page renders, so you can't get future submitted data there. So if you're not submitting the data to the same page you're rendering the form on, you need to render the result to the page from the JS, not from the PHP.

So replace the PHP snippet on your HTML page with a div, like so: `<div id='ajax_output'></div>`, and then write the result to that from the success callback in your Javascript's AJAX call:

```
success: function(data) {
    document.getElementById('ajax_output').innerHTML = data;
}
```

So now your aux.php can just echo the result of `ctrCash` and your AJAX script will pick up that result and display it. So when you call the `ctrCash` function inside your aux.php (which is the script that's actually getting the data), pass `$completeArray` as a parameter (and define it in the function signature as by-reference, like `function ctrCash(&$completeArray)` or similar). The function will have full access to the original array for modification, and after the call, aux.php can echo the result however you want it to be displayed.

Comment: Many thanks! It works perfectly. For weeks I had wanted to find a solution to this problem, and I did not get it in any way. Thank you!!!

Comment: One more thing. By doing what you told me, the function receives the array without problems. BUT now the class does not receive the POST variables that it previously received when executing the script inside the form. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: It's been awhile since I've worked with PHP in depth, but as far as I know, superglobals like $_POST should be accessible from everywhere. Are you getting the correct values for your posted variables in the main aux.php file?

Comment: Yes. What I have done is to delete the script as you told me, which made it possible to modify the function and receive the array. Thanks to that script inside the form, I was able to pass the isset that validated the input. Now I do not know what I should do. I'm looking for, but if you can think of something, let me know!

Comment: Currently, your form is reloading the current page, submitting the data to itself. You don't need to do that; the whole point of using AJAX is to avoid reloading the page. So you shouldn't ever be submitting the form; you should only be using your AJAX call to aux.php to submit values. Your aux.php script can do whatever checking it needs to ensure the value is set.